# featured_media graphql query working locally but not on deployed WP backend

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I recently completed a course by Tom Phillips on Udemy (https://www.udemy.com/share/101XRSAEEedF5aQH4D/) and I was able to complete the course and it was working fine until I started to modify the code for my own personal portfolio. I have a WP back end deployed on Digital Ocean and my front end is hosted on Netlify.

The specific problem I am having seems to be that there is no data being returned for a custom post type of "portfolio" The deploy logs state the following:

```
> failed Building static HTML for pages - 5.032s
> error Building static HTML failed for path "/portfolio/"
> 
> 58 |                   style={{ margin: "1rem", maxWidth: "345" }}
> 59 | 
> 60 |                   {console.log(portfolioItem.node.featured_media.source_url)}
>    |                                                                
> 61 |                   <ImageWrapper>
> 62 |                     <FeaturedImage>
> 63 |                       <CardMedia
>
> WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'source_url' of null
>
> - PortfolioItems.js:60 
> src/components/portfolio/PortfolioItems.js:60:66
>
> - PortfolioItems.js:54
> src/components/portfolio/PortfolioItems.js:54:50
​>
> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> "build.command" failed                                        
> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
​>
> Error message
> Command failed with exit code 1: gatsby build
​>
> Error location
> In Build command from Netlify app:
> gatsby build
​
> Resolved config
> build:
> command: gatsby build
> commandOrigin: ui
> environment:
> - API_PROTOCOL
> - API_URL
> - NODE_VERSION
> publish: /opt/build/repo/public>
```

The StaticQuery looks like:

```
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        {
          allWordpressWpPortfolio {
            edges {
              node {
                excerpt
                content
                title
                slug
                featured_media {
                  source_url
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `}
      render={props => (
        <PortfolioItemsWrapper>
          <Grid
            container
            // direction="column"
            justify="center"
            alignItems="center"
          >
            {props.allWordpressWpPortfolio.edges.map(portfolioItem => (
              <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                <Card
                  key={portfolioItem.node.id}
                  style={{ margin: "1rem", maxWidth: "345" }}
                >
                  {console.log(portfolioItem.node.featured_media.source_url)}
                  <ImageWrapper>
                    <FeaturedImage>
                      <CardMedia
                        style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}
                        image={portfolioItem.node.featured_media.source_url}
                        title="Thumbnail"
                        component="img"
                      />
                    </FeaturedImage>
                  </ImageWrapper>
                  <h2>{portfolioItem.node.title}</h2>

                  <div
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                      __html: portfolioItem.node.excerpt,
                    }}
                  />
                  <Link to={`/portfolio/${portfolioItem.node.slug}`}>
                    Read more...
                  </Link>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </PortfolioItemsWrapper>
      )}
    />
```

Since it is working locally when the WP site is hosted on localhost using the app Local, I assume there is something in my WP config on Digital Ocean that is preventing access but I am not familiar with PHP and am having trouble finding the error. My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
    php_value post_max_size 128M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 300
    php_value max_input_time 300
    
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

If there is something more you need from Wordpress config, let me know. I am not sure what else would be relevant to the issue. The wp-admin settings are identical in my Local localhost version and in the deployed version

Comment: Can you put the full component where you are using the `staticQuery` (not parts of it because it loses the context)

Comment: Thanks @FerranBuireu I have edited question with full StaticQuery tag. As mentioned, this works perfectly locally though just not on the deployed site so my hunch is that it is a WP configuration error and not a react syntax error but let me know if this helps. Thanks again!

Comment: just try local gatsby with remote WP ? ... this post/CPT simply doesn't have a featured image ? you're not testing this possibility in react

Answer (score 0):

According to your `staticQuery`:

```
     query={graphq` {
      allWordpressWpPortfolio {
        edges {
          node {
            excerpt
            content
            title
            slug
            featured_media {
              source_url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `}
```

And how the `console.log` looks like:

```
 {console.log(portfolioItem.node.featured_media.source_url)}
```

It seems to me that you are not looping through the correct object. Once you get the data, the `render` method of the `staticQuery` should look like:

```
    render={(data) => {
      data.allWordpressWpPortfolio.edges.node(portfolioItem =>{
          console.log("Your node image is", portfolioItem.featured_media.source_url)
          return <div>The title is {portfolioItem.title}</div>
      })
    })
```

Alternatively, check the Node versions of both environments and try to equal the dependency versions. Try to build it locally before pushing it to Netlify.

Comment: Thanks Ferran. The structure of the static query is fine. The whole application works as expected when in my development environment (running gatsby develop in the repo root serves my front end to 8000 and Local is running my WP back end on port 3000). The issue only occurs once the front end is deployed to netlify and the WP is deployed to Digital Ocean.

Comment: Check the Node versions of both environments